# Selenium openWindow in IE9 results in "Object Expected" error

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Command openWindow(url, ID) in Selenium errors out in IE9. Works fine in Firefox 9.

Here is my simplified Selenium test case:

1. Open a main page on localhost:8080/myPage/index.html.
2. While keeping this page open, open additional browser window that points
   to    localhost:8181.

The base URL for my test case is 'http://localhost:8080/'. Test case:

```
 <br><br>open | /myPage/index.html | |
 <br>openWindow | http://localhost:8181 | A |
```

This runs without any issues in Selenium IDE 1.7.1 and in Selenium RC 2.12 and 2.19 against Firefox 9. Running it against IE9 via RC 2.12 and 2.19 results in the following error:

```
info: Executing: |openWindow | http://localhost:8181 | A |<br>
error: Unexpected Exception: Object expected<br>
error: Exception details: message -> Object expected, description -> Object expected, number -> -2146823281, name -> TypeError<br>
warn: currentTest.recordFailure: Command execution failure.<br>
Please search the user group at groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window. The error message is: Object expected
```